# (Batch) How ombine multiples different file types into one package?

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off

Hello World!
```

For the past couple days I've been messing with Batch. I made a text based game where you make choices that affect the game and user.

I need to take multiple different file types. Compile or combine them into a single executable. I don't want to send this out as a .rar. If the user would view them it could spoil the story.

For example:

Game.bat, is looking at:

```
intro.txt

character1.txt

character2.txt

character3.txt

character4.txt

sound1.mp3

sound2.mp3
```

Perhaps I went at this the with the wrong method?

Many thanks!

```
false_positive

pause > nu; :P
```

Answer (score 1):

So I'm not entirely sure if this will answer your question, but I was looking for something similar to group together a bunch of batch files into a single executable that starts with a menu batch. But this site [here](http://mintywhite.com/software-reviews/maintenance-software/iexpress-convert-batfiles-exefiles-howto/) walks through how to use the program iExpress which is built into windows from the days of DOS I guess. anyways It was enough to do what I needed it to. Best of luck anyways!